# NoClassDefFoundError after introducing Aspectj into a Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj

I've been trying to introduce more exhaustive logging into a Spring Boot app using Aspectj. However, I cannot get even a very basic solution to work due to a cryptic error that I keep getting on application startup at runtime:

```
2021-05-27 15:38:50,151 [TRACE ] FailureAnalyzers.loadFailureAnalyzers(FailureAnalyzers.java:79) ? Failed to load org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.ValidationExceptionFailureAnalyzer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidationException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.loadFailureAnalyzers(FailureAnalyzers.java:74) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:65) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:59) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:200) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:441) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:427) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.App.main(App.java:37) [classes!/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [quartal-mw-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [quartal-mw-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [quartal-mw-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [quartal-mw-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ValidationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92) ~[quartal-mw-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    ... 26 more
2021-05-27 15:38:50,156 [TRACE ] FailureAnalyzers.loadFailureAnalyzers(FailureAnalyzers.java:79) ? Failed to load org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.InvalidConfigurationPropertiesFailureAnalyzer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.InvalidConfigurationPropertiesFailureAnalyzer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92) ~[quartal-mw-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:277) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.loadFailureAnalyzers(FailureAnalyzers.java:74) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:65) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:59) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:200) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:441) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:427) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.App.main(QuartalMiddlewareApp.java:37) [classes!/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [quartal-mw-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [quartal-mw-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [quartal-mw-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [quartal-mw-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
```

Additions I made to the project are as follows:

AspectLoggingConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AspectLoggingConfig {

    @Bean
    public TraceLoggingAspect traceLoggingAspect() {
        return new TraceLoggingAspect();
    }

}
```

TraceLoggingAspect.java

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class TraceLoggingAspect {

    @Pointcut("within(@com.mycompany.app *)")
    public void withinQuartalMw() {
    }

    @Around("withinQuartalMw()")
    public void advice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        try {
            Object output = joinPoint.proceed();
            log.trace("method" + joinPoint.getSignature() + "was called with output" + output);
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            log.trace(throwable.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>javabuild.intranet.mycompany.com</id>
            <url>http://javabuild.intranet.mycompany.com/nexus</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Searching yields largely irrelevant results; the problems that other people are having with this error are all different, and none of the solutions presented to them work for this case.  I do not see how at all this error relates to the changes I have made, or what to change to get the app working as intended.

Comment: These generally mean a missing dependency. Do you have the `javax.validation` dependency and/or are you accidentally using the ValidationException somewhere? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api Also, this apparently can be the result of a misconfigured Spring project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14976

Comment: Nope, ValidationException is used nowhere in the application code. The whole thing was working fine until I added the changes above. As for the possibly misconfigured project, what exactly is the misconfiguration in this case?

Comment: Read the comment in that ticket: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14976#issuecomment-433604171

Comment: Based on that coment, I tried adding spring-boot-starter-aop into the pom, still the same outcome.

Comment: I think that publishing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub would help you get a solution for your problem. Try to minimise the project and strip off everything, until you reach the minimal configuration and code which still reproduces the error. Then publish it. A reproducible problem is usually much more easily solved than one only described in a question with bits and pieces of information.

Comment: That's not feasible, I'm afraid. This is a proprietary app, using some in-house libraries, and supposed to run only on a specific environment. I don't think I could reliably put together  a MCVE while preserving everything relevant. I don't even know what else is relevant in the app, besides the added code written out in the question.